# My website has been marked as dangerous by Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, security

Recently, I made a social media app by using Next.js typescript and sanity database. I hosted my website in replit. But as I opened it in my google chrome browser, it is showing deceptive site ahead and the cause is being shown as phishing. I don't understand why is google showing that as I have no malware inside my app, nor my app starts installing anything or reveal personal information. It is a simple pwa!

As it is social media app, it needs to take user information for creating account, is it the problem?

I tried contacting google support but couldn't find their email.

Answer (score 3):

**Hey!** If you believe your website was incorrectly flagged by Google's Phishing Detection, I provided a link for you below to request a review :)

https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/?hl=en

Comment: Thanks, I have reported the error. Can you also tell me how much time will it take and also if it actually works :)

Comment: Google seems to have gone crazy with flagging websites as dangerous that are not. http://trilight.cloud/alerts is currently flagged too, but it doesn't have any phishing attempts as far as I can tell.